# Accessing the "session key" cookie name from anywhere in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, cookies

We are building a plugin for Rails to be used within iframe Facebook applications, and at one point we need to check if Rail's session id cookie as been set or not.

By default, this cookie is named *_myprojectname_session*, what we need to find out is the actual name of the cookie itself. So if it's not set, we can do some redirects to make sure the cookies are set.

How do we access the damn name of the cookie from anywhere? Or at least from within a controller?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found the solution. In Rails 2.3.2 at least the session key in set in `config/initializers/session_store.rb` like this:

```
ActionController::Base.session = {
  :key         => '_myapp_session',
  :secret      => '[...]'
}
```

And you can read the value like this:

```
ActionController::Base.session_options[:key]
```

From `Base.session` to `Base.session_options` automagically, doesn't make much sense, and it caused me a big headache... lol

Comment: Thanks, i've spent half an hour trying to work out where this was

Answer (score 40):

```
Rails.application.config.session_options[:key]
```

Answer (score 2):

To access the name of the session cookie from within the view or the controller, you can say:

```
request.session_options[:session_key]
```

and then to access the raw value of that cookie, being an empty array if it's not set, you use:

```
request.cookies[ request.session_options[:session_key] ]
```

The cookie name ( aka session_key ) is set in your `config/environment.rb` file.

```
  config.action_controller.session = {     
    :session_key => '_project_session',
    :secret      => 'long-secret-key'
  }
```

Comment: Hmmm, it doesn't seem to work. I'm using Rails 2.3.2, and the request.session_options hash contains a key called :key rather than :session_key. And it's set to "_session_id" rather than "_myapp_session" as it should be... lol

Comment: Note that in Rails 2 you might need to call `.to_sym` on the session key to actually access the value from `cookies[<session key>]`, eg `request.cookies[request.session_options[:session_key].to_sym]`

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, if there is an underscore in the key, IE SOMETIMES does not set the cookies. In other words, use 'projectsession' instead of '_project_session'.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the session key is stored in a variable called ENV_SESSION_KEY

Answer (score 0):

Note also this bug which affects tests around session_options in some versions of Rails 2.x: https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/2303-testrequest-doesnt-initialize-session_options

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 3/4 I'm using this:

```
request.env["rack.request.cookie_hash"]
```

This is a hash that contains all the cookies for current user including the one for session.
The hash has as a key the name of the cookie, and as a value the value of the cookie

Answer (score -1):

I couldn't work out how to do this in rails 3 :-(

Eventually I ended up putting this in config/initializers/session_store.rb

```
SESSION_KEY = '_myapp_session'
MyApp::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, :key => SESSION_KEY
```

and then accessing this where needed, eg in a view...

```
<%= ::ENV_SESSION_KEY %>
```