# Retrieve JSON maintaining Browser Session

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby, curl

I have a site done in Ruby on Rails which handles user authentication. Now I have a PHP application in the same site under a subfolder that retrieves a JSON provided by RoR specifying user role.

Now when I try to retrieve the JSON from PHP, it always retrieves as 'Guest' even if a user is logged in (I believe because browser session is not maintained). The code I use to retrieve JSON is

```
$json_url = 'https://mysite.com.com/usertype';
$json_string = '[usertype]';
// Initializing curl
$ch = curl_init( $json_url );
// Configuring curl options
$options = array(
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-type: application/json') ,
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $json_string
);
// Setting curl options
curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );
// Getting results
$result =  curl_exec($ch); // Getting jSON result string
```

Now is there something someone can help me with where in I can retrieve the JSON maintaining the session????

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3097451/sharing-a-session-between-ruby-and-php

Comment: Both the applications are on the same domain, there are no sub domains involved. So, is there a easier way?

Comment: The first part of that answer isn't domain specific and would work

Answer (score 1):

RoR will set an authentication cookie. So the first step is to find out that cookie name. The default name is "_myprojectname_session", but it can be changed in `config/initializers/session_store.rb` (see [Accessing the "session key" cookie name from anywhere in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001597/accessing-the-session-key-cookie-name-from-anywhere-in-rails)).

An easy way to find out the cookie name is to see it in the browser (for example, using this chrome extension: http://code.google.com/p/editthiscookie/).

Once you find out the cookie name (for example "_myapp_session"), You need to copy the session cookie from the PHP request to the CURL options, like this:

```
$options = array(
CURLOPT_COOKIE => "_myapp_session=" . $_COOKIE['_myapp_session'],
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-type: application/json') ,
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $json_string
);
```

Comment: I tired it and it still shows the user and signed out when he actually is signed out

Comment: I tried your method, unfortunately, it still doesn't read properly, guess the session cookie is not being read/set properly...